# How do I setup a Tableau alert for when a table contains data?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a SQL query that usually results in zero records. Sometimes this query does show data and in those cases I need to send out an alert so that the responsible person can look at the table asap. Since there is normally not any data I am unable to "select a numeric axis" to create an alert. So far I've tried creating a calculated field: `IF ISNULL(ID) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END` and using that field as the numeric axis. Unfortunately, this did not resolve my issue. How can I setup this sort of alert in Tableau?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use subscriptions with the 'Don't send if view is empty' option selected-

[image: Tableau Subscribe Window]

So, when data is present, run the subscription, else do not send.

Comment: Thanks Bob, that did the trick. We didn't have subscriptions enabled so I had to do that first.